# NullPointerException from service when use repository

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I have a question about the unit test.  I am writing a test to check if the service saves the data correctly (i.e. does not make a duplicate)
There is a service class that has several fields, we are interested in TypeRepository field. In the method for saving it is called and the find method is used... in this case when I run the test I get NullPointerException.  I don't know exactly what can help in this case. I would be grateful for help

**Service**

```java
@Service
@Slf4j
public class Service {
    ... 
    ...
    final RiskRepo riskRepo;
    ...
    ...
    private Limit validate(Limit newLimit) {
   
        RiskType.Value typeValue
                = riskRepo.findDistinctLimitTypeValueByLimitType(newLimitType);
                      //  ^--- exception
        
        switch (typeValue) { <-- warning can be null  
            case CONTY: {
                ...
                break;
            }

    ...
}
```

**Repo**

```java
public interface Repo extends JpaRepository<Limit, Integer> {


    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT r.Value from Type r WHERE r.limit=?1")
    RiskType.Value findDistinctValueByLimit(String limitType);
}
```

**Test**

```java
 @Test
    public void test_validate() {
        Limit newLimit = Limit.builder()
                .riskType(...)
                ......build();

        limitService.create(newLimit);
        List<Limit>  limits = limitRepository.findAllByRiskTypeAndEntityAndLimitTypeAndUnitAndActive(
                newLimit.getRiskType(), newLimit.getEntity(), newLimit.getLimitType(),newLimit.getUnit(),newLimit.getActive());
        Assert.assertEquals(1, limits.size());
    }
```

Comment: If you are doing a unit test, then you need to mock `RiskRepo`. Are you doing that?

Comment: There is too little information here to answer the question. Where is exception thrown? What does the full test look like, what does your service look like. All that, crucial, information is missing. In the current state the question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write more code of your test class, because it can be a test configuration problem or something that is not on these pieces of code. But first things first, make sure you're injecting the repository on your service, it doesn't look like it is, so annotate the repository attribute with @Autowired or create a constructor and initiate the repository instance inside him. Another thing that can cause a problem is that your service method is private, it needs to be public, otherwise only the service class can access it.

About the tests, usually when I do these kinds of tests, they can be mocked or integrated.

**Mocked test:**

You gotta use an annotation such as @RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class) above the service test class. Then inject the service and mock the repository that you are using with @Mock (repo) and  @InjectMocks (service).

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class YourTestClass {

@InjectMocks
private LimitService service;

@Mock
private LimitRepository repository;

@Test
public void test_validate(){
  
  when(this.repository...).thenReturn(...);

  this.service.doSomething();

  verify(this.repository).doSomething(...);
  verifyNoMoreInteractions(this.repository);
}
```

**Integration test:**

Here what you are going to do is almost the same as a repository test, the diference is that you are going to need to call the SERVICE that will call the repository method. You'll need to config your class to run the context like the repository tests do.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class EmployeeRestControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private LimitService service;

    // write test cases here (such as your own, asserting the result of the service method return)
}
```

So these would be solutions for these two types of service testing, now if you need to test the repository, I suggest looking into Spring Boot repository testing.

Comment: Thank you for your response, very well explained how to work in this case, I also did a little poking around the sites and found a pretty handy @Before. . in this case, it helped, thank you for pointing the right way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by using the @Before method to initialize the repository and write test data to the database

```java
@Before
    public void setup() {
  Type type = new Type(
               data..);
        TypeRepository.save(type);

}
```